# Authorize.net CIM responding error

Tags: magento, response, authorize.net

I am using live account on my magento store.While doing transaction I am getting below error message.So please help me why this is happening.

```
 [resultCode] => Error
        [messages] => stdClass Object
            (
                [MessagesTypeMessage] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [code] => E00027
                        [text] => This transaction has been declined.
                    )

            )

        [directResponse] => 2,1,4,This transaction has been declined.,000000,R,7962739058,100000052,test payment,249.00,CC,auth_capture,5,Kren,Brow,,130 Indianwood Drive,Brofield,Wiscin,53005,US,<<ph no.>>,,nwood@aerer.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<<key>>,,,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX5454,MasterCard,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Charlotte .... Can you check if your configuration is setup correctly? Can you paste a screenshot in your post of what you see under System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > ACIM / Authorize.net (CIM)

Comment: The "problem" is clear. The card was declined by the bank.That means the connection was successful and the credit  card is just bad.

Comment: @Shivani Yes I set up configuration for this payment method is correct.Because I am getting this error in one transaction only out of 5.

Comment: @john My client is placed many orders with same credit card before.But this time only I am getting this error.

Comment: Is the name which is entered during the checkout process in the Credit Card (Authorize.net) section same as on the card that is being used?

Comment: @shivani I am using magento's default payment method,which has 4 fields CC type,CC no. ,Expiry date and AVS. There is no field of Name.

Comment: @CharlotteAc ... Currently, from the [directResponse], I think the Reason Code is 2 which means there is an issue with the card. Maybe you can login to the LIVE Authorize.net account and look around - Customer Information Manager. This can be a start point (not sure if this will help). Delete all entries of that customer with that card info and try again.